# A taxi was involved in a hit-and-run accident last night

Tags: mathematics, probability

A taxi was involved in a hit-and-run accident at night. Two taxi companies, the green and the blue, operate in the city.  85% percent of the taxis are green and 15% are blue.  A witness identified the taxi as blue.The witness identifies the correct color 80% of the time and fails 20% of the time.  What is the probability that the taxi was blue?

Comment: Since your answer is wrong, perhaps you're not the best judge of where the post belongs.

Comment: What about mine?

Comment: @BobRodes, my mistake. I didn't realise there was more to it.

Comment: As someone who *did* get the correct answer (before looking at the submitted ones), I’m not at all sure why this is in puzzling rather than just math.stackexchange.  It seems like a straightforward probability exercise dressed up in a word problem, and with several important assumptions (e.g. that the witness’s chance of correctness is independent of the colour of the taxi) omitted.  There’s no particular imagination or insight involved.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I'm not at all sure why anyone cares.  I thought the point of this site was to have fun, rather than to count coups in terms of who better understands the rules.  But maybe I misunderstand, and this place isn't about having fun at all, but rather a vehicle to promote the fantasy of right vs. wrong.  After all, I'm new here.

Comment: This is an elementary Bayesian statistics problem.

Comment: @f'' Good to know.

Comment: Also apparently a very well-known example: https://www.google.com/search?q="A+witness+identified+the+taxi+as+blue."

Comment: In google all mysteries are resolved.  :)

Comment: @BobRodes it is completely normal to make mistakes when you join a new forum, everyone does. But when other, more experienced users tell you you are wrong, you don't need to become hostile. This indeed is place for having fun, but in order to improve the experience, we try to stick to some posting rules.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan Thanks for the reminder.  Of course there should be posting rules.  I wasn't irritated that our mutual friend above was saying I was wrong, but I did find his holier-than-thou attitude irritating.  Perhaps more than I should have.

Comment: @BobRodes: apologies if I came off as sanctimonious or heavy-handed, I just wanted to explain why I felt it was off-topic (since at that point it had received several downvotes but no explanation).

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Four years down the line, I can see that I have behaved badly here, and would like to apologize. Sorry for my bad behavior, and thank you for your graciousness in handling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 12/29

Because

> the chance of it being blue and the witness being correct is 0.12. Or he saw blUE but it was green, which is a 0.17 chance. 0.12/(0.12+0.17)= 12/29.

Comment: what do you mean "blUE but it was green". Could you explain that?

Comment: He's referring to the chances that a blue car was incorrectly identified as green, which your answer doesn't take into account.

Comment: The witness incorrectly identified a green taxi as blue = 85%*20%

Comment: @bob nope, the opposite :p

Comment: Well done!  I'll have to come up with something tougher, although when I last tried a year ago, several people marked my problem as a dup of another problem which actually had a different answer.

Comment: Thats clever I didn't think of that. @BobRodes, maybe add something in the question saying its more complicated than you think, so you don't get the downvotes. I'm taking mine away anyway

Comment: Oh yes, you did say the opposite.  Both have to be taken into consideration.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Ya maybe, but I really don't care about downvotes.

Comment: Okay, I always stunk at probability, but this doesn't seem right to me, so help me understand. The witness sees the taxi, says it's blue, and is right 80% of the time.  So why isn't it just 80%?